# filter on pandas dataframe is not working and adding NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a below dataframe and I m trying to filter the values but its not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfRUl.png)

> > > lookup_dfd
> > > User     Subject     Marks   Grade
> > > 0  Asma     SUB A       36        Pass
> > > 1  Asma     SUB B       106       Fail
> > > 2  Asma     SUB C       15        Pass
> > > 3  Asma     SUB D       11        Pass

When I m running this below command, its not filtering the rows instead showing NaN for other rows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niGfl.png)

> > > lookup_df[lookup_df.Marks == 36]
> > > User     Subject     Marks   Grade
> > > 0  Asma     SUB A       36      Pass
> > > 1  NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN
> > > 2  NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN
> > > 3  NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN

I have also tried to add more filters but still the same results. Refer images

Comment: please follow this guide for posting good questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I notice your images have different code to what you have written down.  For you filtering on column `Volume` when it produces a strange result, and your initial dataframe is `lookup_dfd`.  Have you tried running the code you have pasted as text in this question?  When I tried that I didn't receive the Nan values.